# Image is not generated and Replicate does not end

Tags: next.js, replicate

I can't get out of the loop, although I can see in my dashboard on replicate.com that the request only took 3.5 seconds and an image was also generated. Occasionally, no idea why, the status is successful, but standard moderate is processed. How come?

```
 // GET request to get the status of the image restoration process & return the result when it's ready
 let generatedImage: string | null = null;
 while (!generatedImage) {
  // Loop in 1s intervals until the alt text is ready
  let finalResponse = await fetch(endpointUrl, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Token " + process.env.REPLICATE_API_KEY,
    },
  });
  let jsonFinalResponse = await finalResponse.json();
  console.log(jsonFinalResponse)
  if (jsonFinalResponse.status === "succeeded") {
    generatedImage = jsonFinalResponse.output[1] as string;
    break;
  } else if (jsonFinalResponse.status === "failed") {
    break;
  } else {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}
```